# Validation Rule

Tags: validation

I may need assistance to help me fix the VR.

```
CASE(Support__c,

"1 - App Support",1,
"2 - Case Support",2,
"3 - Dev Team",3,
"4 - Salesforce Premiere Support",4,0)
    <

CASE(PRIORVALUE(Support__c),

"1 - App Support",1,
"2 - Case Support",2,
"3 - Dev Team",3,
"4 - Salesforce Premiere Support",4,0) && 
NOT( $$Profile.Id !="0056F000005Lhik", 
    $Profile.Id !="0056F000005bDQl", 
    $Profile.Id !="00590000001eKS7")
```

Comment: As an aside, it's probably more efficient to write something like `TEXT(Support__c) < TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Support__c))`. Also, using something like `Profile.Id` is probably better done as a Custom Permission; it'll make your validation rule more maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT only takes one parameter. You simply need to use && to join the Boolean values together.

```
CASE(...) <
CASE(...) &&
NOT( $Profile.Id !="0056F000005Lhik" && 
$Profile.Id !="0056F000005bDQl" &&
$Profile.Id !="00590000001eKS7")
```